# MySQL/Python INSERT INTO Statement Issues

Tags: python, mysql, database

I'm attempting to test adding data to a database via python. I have recognized that many people have issues with the "INSERT INTO" statement, and I have as well. I have received a range of errors, followed by changing the syntax multiple times, and then receiving new errors.

Currently, I have this as my statement:

```
cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO test (Column 1,Column 2) VALUES (%s,%s)"""% arg)
```

Where:

```
arg=("'5','2'")
```

Running the code outputs the standard 1064 MySQL error.

If someone can explain to me the standard syntax that would be great, because I can't seem to find it anywhere.

Comment: Looks like you are passing a single argument when it is expecting 2.  What is the error you are getting?

Comment: If arg is already one string containing the two elements of the query like shown, then the query string should contain only one %s -> (%s)

Comment: MySQL errors typically include information about where in the query MySQL had a problem; including that in your question can help diagnose the issue. (The error number itself can often be the least helpful part of the error message.)

Comment: Hi all, thank you for your comments. The MySQL error I am getting is 1064 which is a standard syntax error. @user3483203.

Comment: @cabbi I have edited my code to reflect this suggestion, and results in "TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I appreciate your answers but I found a solution. I ended up changing the rows in the DB to "Column1" instead of "Column 1", and this solved the issue.

```
 import MySQLdb as mariadb


db = mariadb.connect(host="", user="root", passwd="", db="")
 cursor = db.cursor()
 sql = "INSERT INTO test (Column 1,Column 2) VALUES (%s,%s)"
#sqltime=datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
arg = ('5',"'2'") #argument input 

 try:
  cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO test (Column1,Column2) VALUES (%s,%s)"""% arg)  
db.commit()
except:
cursor.execute('show profiles')
for row in cursor:
    print(row)
raise
db.close()
```

Comment: It looks like you changed how `arg` was initialized, are you sure that isn't what solved your issue? _First time it was a string containing comma separated values, now it is an array/list of strings._

Comment: @Uueerdo You maybe correct, but the arg statement works even if you get rid of the double quotes on the last value. So I am not sure exactly. I currently have ('6','3')  and it works fine as well.

Comment: Hmm, I am not that familiar with python, but the code you've shown here looks like Column1 will get `5` and Column2 will get `'2'` _with the single-quotes included._

Comment: @Uueerdo Yes that is what happens. If I'm being honest, this is the first time I've ever worked with databases so it's all new to me!! Haha. Figuring it out one step at at time.

Comment: Everyone was new at some point. By putting the `'` inside the `"` you told python you wanted single quotes in the string value, similar to how something like `O'Brian` or `Todd's truck` would need them.

Answer (score 0):

If fields or tables have spaces or other special characters in their names, they need delimited with `.

```
INSERT INTO test (`Column 1`,`Column 2`) ...
```

It is also a good habit to get into because it prevents hard to diagnose issues with using identifiers that might be confused with reserved or keywords.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but upon editing my code I still run into errors. The error this time states "TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting"

Answer (score 0):

try this one out. I changed the `%` -> `,` and added the values at the end

```
cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO test (`Column 1`,`Column 2`) VALUES (%s,%s)""", (5,2))
```

Comment: This did in fact work. I will mark it as the correct answer when I am able. Thank you very much.

Comment: @SwankyTigers no problem! glad to help

Answer (score 0):

It is never the best way to deal with these problems, but it always works to use the `"".join(string)`

```
arg=(5,2)
query = "".join(["INSERT INTO test (Column 1,Column 2) VALUES (" , str(arg[0]), ", ", str(arg[1]),")"])
query

Out[25]: 'INSERT INTO test (Column 1,Column 2) VALUES (5, 2)'
```

And then you `execute()` it. Cheers !

Comment: When would you suggest using join versus not? I am new to this so I am trying to get a sense of what practices are "Best" and which are not.

Comment: Generally, it is better to use as specified above. However, this method makes you not having to "learn" the command as up for each package since it always works. However, you should be carerful whether you pass strings or numbers because if you mix them it can get messy